# Why doesn't "verde" become "verda" when paired with a feminine noun?

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, conjugación, género

Why does "verde" remain the same whereas "blanco" becomes "blanca" and "rojo" becomes "roja" in this sentence?

"*La bandera italiana es verde, blanca y roja*"

Green ("verde") retains the same spelling, but white and red get "feminized" - why the inconsistency? What makes green different? (Why doesn't it become "verda"?)

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Por qué el color “marrón” no tiene femenino “marrona”? En general, ¿por qué tan pocos colores tienen género femenino diferenciado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28112/5481) Parece ser que los colores cuyos nombres provienen de sustantivos, son invariables en género.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Spanish there are words adjectives that work as if they have neutral gender. They do not work as masculine nor feminine.

In fact they are not neutral. There is no neutral gender in spanish. It happens that the word is **invariable**: its form is the same in masculine and feminine.

Easy examples are "verde", "azul", "naranja", "común", "inteligente", "amable".

Comment: Indeed. https://static1.elcorreo.com/www/multimedia/201902/22/media/cortadas/respuesta-rae-kLlE-U70737488701HdF-624x385@El%20Correo.jpeg