# ¿Por qué el color "marrón" no tiene femenino "marrona"? En general, ¿por qué tan pocos colores tienen género femenino diferenciado?

Tags: adjetivos, género, colores

Dentro del precioso proceso de aprendizaje del idioma, mi hija de tres años ya ha cogido bastante soltura. Ello se ve con la facilidad que deduce palabras en función de las reglas que poco a poco va asimilando.

Ella claro, ya entiendo que existe el género masculino y femenino para los adjetivos. Y del mismo modo que si decimos que *el coche es **blanco*** y luego *la pelota es **blanca***, automáticamente intuye que si *el árbol es **marrón*** entonces *la silla es **marrona***.

Pero claro, todos hemos levantado la ceja al leer *marrona* porque sabemos que para este adjetivo el femenino también es *marrón*.

Entonces estuve investigando un poco y vi que en la Wikipedia se habla de [Género de los colores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9nero_de_los_colores) y de que hay dos hipótesis sobre *el bajo porcentaje de colores que tengan flexión de género*:

> los colores con género corresponden a coloraciones de pelo en humanos y animales.

y

> los colores con género corresponden a las tonalidades encontradas en las pinturas rupestres de la península ibérica.

Y me pregunto: ¿hay algún estudio extenso al respecto? ¿Alguna de las dos hipótesis tiene mayor recepción entre la comunidad lingüística?

Comment: Ya me dirás qué humano o animal tiene de forma natural el pelo morado. O qué pintura rupestre se ha encontrado morada. :)

Comment: Por cierto, como color tal vez no, pero como sustantivo sí se puede decir que algo es una _marrona_ (por aquí se usa a veces como variante jocosa de _marrón_ con la acepción de "situación u obligación molesta, desagradable o embarazosa").

Comment: Que curioso la verdad, nunca había pensado en ello. Lo de los colores de pelo tampoco me cuadra, si aceptamos *amarillo* como rubio (que ya es raro) también debería estar el *marrón*.

Comment: Relacionado: [Why doesn't “verde” become “verda” when paired with a feminine noun?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5741/5481)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Marrón* proviene del francés *marron* /maʁɔ̃/ "castaña", y como otros colores cuyos nombres provienen de sustantivos, es invariable en género. (En francés también se utiliza *marron* como color y es invariable inclusive en número.)

[image: Wiktionary: marron]

*Color marrón* significa entonces "color castaña", que formalmente es incorrecto; debería ser "color **de** castaña". De la misma manera decimos *color ratón, color manzana*, todos ellos invariables en género y número; *marrón*, como *naranja*, ya se lexicalizó lo suficiente como adjetivo como para concordar en número con el sustantivo que modifica.

Comment: Fíjate en este tuit: _"'Castaño' hemos de decir, que no 'marrón'". Del libro "¡Pobre lengua! Catálogo en que se indican más de cuatrocientas voces y locuciones incorrectas hoy comunes en España". Año 1908_ https://twitter.com/lirondos/status/1100517655059091456

Comment: Ah y la autora habló de ello en su artículo de eldiario.es [*'Marrona' y los adjetivos 'wannabe'*](https://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/Marrona-adjetivos-wannabe_6_871822834.html)

Answer (score 4):

> **French SE:** [Pourquoi ces 6 adjectifs de couleur s'accordent même s'ils référencent un nom?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7537/15770)

There are different classes of colour adjective in Spanish, corresponding to differing degrees of lexicalisation. As the language evolves words may adapt and progress from one class to another.

### 1. Old colours: gender & number

The oldest colour terms are fully lexicalised and inflect for both gender and number:

- blanco, negro, rojo, amarillo

This includes a number of terms for shades of red (among other colours):

- rubio, carrubio, rúbeo, rútilo, rufo, royo, roso, rubicundo
- albo, pardo, tinto, flavo, indio, cerúleo, coccíneo, glauco, cárdeno, rodeno, endrino, bermejo, sobermejo, colorado, alzán/alzano, zarco, cándido

There was a richness of such colours in centuries past, but many of these have fallen out of modern use:

- blavo, bazo, hosco, presado, leucofeo, rucio, musco/musgo, loro, albero, gilvo

Note that some of these are gender invariant due to their morphology:

- azul, verde, gris, añil, carmesí
- `antiquated` jalde, buriel, blao, azur, albar, rubor

### 2. Old colours: number

A few of these historic colour adjectives have stubbornly remained invariant for gender though:

- púrpura, escarlata, índigo

These appear to have been blocked by parallel forms developing (*purpúreo/a, indio/a*).

### 3. New colours: (number)

Newer colour adjectives are usually nouns which have been co-opted for their appearance. As such, more recent ones are generally treated as noun-complements, and not adjectives proper, and are invariant for gender. The longer they have been in the lexicon the more likely they are to inflect for number however:

- `flowers` rosa, violeta, lila, lavanda, malva, fucsia, azafrán, grosella, amaranto, bujarasol
- `fruit` naranja, granate, limón, fresa, oliva, marrón, albaricoque, cereza, vainilla
- `wood` caoba, nogal
- `precious stones` turquesa, esmeralda, amatista, ámbar, jade, azabache, marfil, porcelana
- `metals` plata, oro, cobalto
- `minerals etc` ocre, almagre, grana, teja
- `proper names` corinto, carmelita, siena, etíope
- `misc` crema, café, vino, burdeos, sepia, coral, miel, tabaco, lacre, aloque, salmón

Loanwords are treated similarly:

- magenta, bermellón, verdeceledón, cinzolín, rosicler
- cian, caqui, carmín, beis/beige, punzó, grancé, cari

Compound nouns with cardinal colours (e.g. *azul, verde*), and abbreviations thereof, also remain invariant:

- celeste, ultramar, marino, turquí
- verdegay, verdemar, verdemontaña, verdoyo, verdín

### 4. New colours adapted: gender & number

Newer colour adjectives may undergo two methods of lexicalisation to become inflectable adjectives proper.

#### 1. inflection of bare adjective:

- bruno, blondo, cetrino/citrino, habano, columbino, ígneo, prieto, franciscano, solferino, araguato, canario

This does indeed occur with some feminine nouns in *-a*

- castaño, cenizo, canelo, gualdo, cano

#### 2. suffixing:

The most common suffix is *-ado*:

- rosado, violado, (a)naranjado, morado/amoratado/moracho, limonado, datilado, aceitunado, aberenjenado, ahigadado, azafranado, noguerado, (a)brasilado, agarbanzado
- nevado, melado, apizarrado, atabacado, acanelado, achocolatado, ahumado, ahuesado, almacigado/amacigado, gualdado, cañamonado, galbanado, gamuzado, anteado, (re)tostado, (a)nacarado, encarnado, achiotado, acaparrosado, apiñonado, amelcochado, azopilotado, asalmonado, atezado, acarminado, acabellado
- agrisado
- (a)perlado, azufrado, turquesado
- dorado, plateado, bronceado, encobrado, argentado
- leonado, alobunado, alagartado

But a number of others may be adopted:

- moreno, cardenillo, fosforito, trigueño
- ceniciento, peciento/pizmiento
- plomizo, cobrizo, pajizo
- cenizoso, herrumbroso, barroso, cafesoso
- gríseo, róseo, zafíreo, carmíneo, cárneo, sanguíneo
- grisáceo, violáceo, purpúreo, rosáceo, oliváceo, porráceo, ocráceo

Precious stones tend to take *-ino*:

- perlino, zafirino, opalino, esmeraldino, ambarino, encarnadino, purpurino, sanguino

---

**Sources:**

<sup>- *[Lexicalization patterns in color naming: A cross-linguistic perspective](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bZa1DwAAQBAJ)*</sup>
<sup>- *[Colour and colour naming: Crosslinguistic approaches](http://www.elexicography.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Colour-and-coulour-naming-2016-ISBN-9789899866621.pdf)*</sup>
<sup>- The Syntax of Relational Adjectives in Romance: a Cartographic Approach</sup>
<sup>- [DPD: colores](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=O2YJVDPNGD6RHMUmU0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

No soy capaz de encontrar ninguna referencia al respecto, pero claramente los colores con género son  aquéllos que acaban en "-o", ya que entonces se puede convertir al femenino solamente cambiándola por "-a":

- Rojo, roja
- Amarillo, amarilla
- Morado, morada
- Negro, negra
- Blanco, blanca

Intuyo que podría ser una extrapolación de los adjetivos en general; por ejemplo pequeño→pequeña.

No obstante, adjetivos que terminan en "e" son válidos para ambos géneros, como "verde".

Los que ya terminan en "a" en masculino no pueden formarse en femenino sin cambiar la palabra, de modo que se quedan igual:

- Naranja
- Rosa

Y quedarían los que terminan en consonante: gris, azul, marrón... Honestamente sí que no entiendo por qué no se dice grisa, azula y marrona. Uno peude pensar que suena mal, pero suena mal porque no estamos acostumbrados solamente.

En conclusión, yo creo que, más bien, habría que buscar la etimología de los colores, y ver por qué rojo y amarillo terminan en "o", pero no se dice "azulo", por ejemplo.

Comment: Me gusta la simplicidad de esta explicación propuesta, pero hay unas más excepciones: *oro (\*ora), corinto (\*corinta), vino (\*vina), tabaco (\*tabaca); gualda (gualdo), endrina (endrino)*