# ¿El color "púrpura" o "púrpuro"?

Tags: género, colores

"Color" es masculino, por lo que el artículo acompañado es "el".

¿Entonces por qué es "el color púrpura"?

¿O sea no se puede decir, por ejemplo, "un camisón púrpuro"?

Por alguna razón no he podido confirmar durante una búsqueda si existe "púrpuro" cuando se usa como adjetivo.

Comment: Posiblemente esa "a" final sea engañosa y "púrpura" es invariable ne cuanto a género, como "verde" o "marrón" (como ya vimos en [¿Por qué el color “marrón” no tiene femenino “marrona”? En general, ¿por qué tan pocos colores tienen género femenino diferenciado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28112/5481) y en [Why doesn't “verde” become “verda” when paired with a feminine noun?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5741/5481)

Comment: "Purpura" no es femenino. Que termine con a no indica necesarimente femenino

Comment: Para recordarlo facilmente: hay una pelicula llamada [El color púrpura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_color_p%C3%BArpura) - en inglés, The Color Purple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Púrpura](https://dle.rae.es/p%C3%BArpura?m=30_2) es una palabra con los dos géneros: es femenina y masculina. Puede verse en la 9.<sup>a</sup> acepción del DLE. Así que no es necesaria la palabra *púrpuro*.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas respuestas! se me olvidó preguntar si en este contexto "púrpura" puede también puede ser plural. ¡Muchas gracias otra vez !

Answer (score 5):

Además de lo señalado por @VeAqui en [su excelente respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35274/1674), ten en cuenta que [color](https://dle.rae.es/color?) puede ser también *femenino* en las acepciones 1.<sup>a</sup> y 2.<sup>a</sup>, por lo que también es correcto "la color púrpura".